# WebStorm not recognise step-definitions using parameters type (not regexp) in CucumberJS

Tags: webstorm, cucumberjs

I want to use parameter-type functionality of CucumberJS in WebStorm.
Unfortunately, WS does not recognize these steps writing by my own parameter-type.
Does anybody faced this problem or decided on it?

Parameter-type cucumber: https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/

[steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxgaJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue unfortunately, please follow [WEB-39983](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-39983) for updates